# Calculate time complexity of a pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am trying to analyze the time complexity of an algorithm.

The algorithm below is meant to only check one part of the array, so no worries if it doesn't make much sense.

I am very confused about calculating the time complexity around loops, please have a look at my comments.

```
def search(key,arr) 
   N = arr.length                    C1
   for 0 <= i < ceiling(N/2)         C2*N+C3 - ceiling can be considered a constant. 
      if(arr[i] == key):             C4*N -- Assuming this because its inside the loop?
      return 2*i                     C5*N -- N because of the loop?
   return "Not found"                C6
```

Does that mean we have:

T(N) = (C2+C4+C5)N + (C1+C3+C6)

T(N) = C7*N + (C8)

T(N) = N??

Everything inside a loop is always *N?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it would be N/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. This is an `O(n)` algorithm.

But you can't say that everything inside a loop is always times `N`. Consider the following example:

```
for i == N; i >= 0; i /= 2:
  ... do some constant stuff
```

This is obviously logarithmic in `N`, because we half `i` in each iteration.

The key is how your variable approaches the loops bound. If it increments/decrements by constant steps. Then it is linear. But if there is some other operation involved, you need to take that into account.

Comment: so if(arr[i] == key): does equal C4*N, but if the i wasn't there then it would be just C4?
Thanks!

Comment: whatever expression in your for loop, even if it doesn't have the loop variable, if there is a chance that it is evaluated each time then you must multiply it by `N`. It could be `if True == False:` this doesn't have any reference to `i` but is executed `N` times.

Comment: OK, that makes sense!  :) 
For your example then, this one because i / 2 that would mean that this would be Constant time * N/2 in this case?

`for i == N; i >= 0; i / 2:
  ... do some constant stuff`

Comment: No, this would be `log(N) * Constant stuff`. This is because we are dividing `i` by `2` each time. The increment/decrement towards `N` is not constant.